# Making a collapsible list in two directions?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm a beginner programmer, so this question might be a little simple. I'm using the following code in jQuery to simple collapse a list from left to right after the action of mouseclick:

```
$(initlist);
function initlist(){
  $('li:not(:has(ul))').css({cursor:'default','list-style-image':'none'});
  $('li:has(ul)')
    .click(collapse)
    .click()
    .css({cursor:'pointer','list-style-image':'url(plus.gif)'})
    .children().hide();
};
function collapse(event){
  if (this == event.target) {
    $(this).children().toggle();
    $(this).css('list-style-image',
                ($(this).children().is(':hidden')) ? 'url(plus.gif)' :url(minus.gif)');
  }
};
</script>
```

The html are normal unordered lists looking like this:

1. Item 1
2. Item 2

   - Item 4
   - Item 5

     - Item 6

       - Item 8
     - Item 7
3. Item 3

Now I'm trying to find a way -without applying any tags or changing the html code- to make the list also collapsible from top to bottom: Each item being hidden by default and then appearing one by one if for example the down arrow is clicked on the keyboard.
For example the items 1-5 would appear with the actions: down-down-down --> mouseclick on Item 2 --> down-down.

I would really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can wrap the text elements in your lists with an anchor tag (as done below), this whole thing becomes a lot simpler:

```
$('ul').hide()
$('li').contents()
        .filter(function(){return this.nodeType === 3})
        .wrap('<a>');

$('a').click(function() {
    $(this).next('ul').toggle()
})
```

Comment: Thank your for your answer! The problem is that I have hundreds of really long lists with a lot of items, sometimes nested more than 10 areas to the right. So manually tagging the .html files would take me a lot of time. However I don't know alot about regex etc, do you think writing a script to automatically tag all elements of a hierarchy is feasible?

Comment: I tried to implement your code and it seems that all the elements appear on the same nesting level to the left? I need to keep the original list structure intact, just make the items appear sequentially.

Comment: You need to adjust your CSS to put margin-left on UL

Comment: Thank you so much it is nearly perfect! Is it possible to only toggle the next element, like if I click on "Item 2" then only "Item4" appears, and "Item5" only if for example the down arrow is clicked? At the moment 4+5 appear at the same time instantly.